# Correct config location of chartjs-plugin-annotation with ng2-charts?

Tags: angular, chart.js, ng2-charts, chartjs-plugin-annotation

I'm using `ng2-charts` to draw a bar chart in my Angular application. At some point I had to add static lines to my charts, and I decided to use `chartjs-plugin-annotation`. Connecting these two libraries together is not well documented, but after some googling I was eventually able to get it working.

Here is a minimalistic [demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ng2-charts-annotation-example-khyqlj?file=src/app/app.component.ts). Yet while it works well on stackblitz, the IDE on my local machine complains that `annotation` is not expected by `ChartOptions` interface:

```
  public barChartOptions: ChartOptions = {
    responsive: true,
    scales: {
        yAxes: [{
            display: true,
            ticks: {
                suggestedMin: 0
            }
        }]
    },
    // This whole section is underlined in red by IDE
    annotation: {
      drawTime: 'afterDatasetsDraw',
      annotations: [
        {
          type: 'line',
          ...
```

So does the compiler:

```
    ERROR in src/app/calendar/calendar.component.ts(31,5): error TS2322: Type '{ responsive: true; scales: { yAxes: { display: true; ticks: { suggestedMin: number; }; }[]; }; annotation: { drawTime: string; annotations: { type: string; mode: string; scaleID: string; value: number; borderColor: string; borderDash: number[]; borderWidth: number; }[]; }; }' is not assignable to type 'ChartOptions'.
      Object literal may only specify known properties, but 'annotation' does not exist in type 'ChartOptions'. Did you mean to write 'rotation'?
```

Although this warning doesn't prevent the project from compiling, it still doesn't look right.

I checked `ChartOptions`, defined in `node_modules/@types/chart.js/index.d.ts`, and indeed, it doesn't have `annotation` in it (and shouldn't, because this interface is defined in `chart.js` library, who doesn't and shouldn't know anything about plugin specifics):

```
interface ChartOptions {
    responsive?: boolean;
    responsiveAnimationDuration?: number;
    aspectRatio?: number;
    maintainAspectRatio?: boolean;
    events?: string[];
    legendCallback?(chart: Chart): string;
    onHover?(this: Chart, event: MouseEvent, activeElements: Array<{}>): any;
    onClick?(event?: MouseEvent, activeElements?: Array<{}>): any;
    onResize?(this: Chart, newSize: ChartSize): void;
    title?: ChartTitleOptions;
    legend?: ChartLegendOptions;
    tooltips?: ChartTooltipOptions;
    hover?: ChartHoverOptions;
    animation?: ChartAnimationOptions;
    elements?: ChartElementsOptions;
    layout?: ChartLayoutOptions;
    scale?: RadialLinearScale;
    scales?: ChartScales | LinearScale | LogarithmicScale | TimeScale;
    showLines?: boolean;
    spanGaps?: boolean;
    cutoutPercentage?: number;
    circumference?: number;
    rotation?: number;
    devicePixelRatio?: number;
    plugins?: ChartPluginsOptions;
}
```

I tried to re-locate the `annotation` part elsewhere ([`chartjs-plugin-annotation` documentation](https://github.com/chartjs/chartjs-plugin-annotation#configuration) says it should be under `plugins`, which would make total sense), but in all other locations it was just ignored. So eventually, in order to get rid of the warning, I just removed the `: ChartOptions` part - that is, instead of this:

```
  public barChartOptions: ChartOptions = {
```

I wrote just this:

```
  public barChartOptions = {
```

That removed the warnings, but it still does not look neat enough. Does anyone have any idea how to use this plugin properly?

Comment: I'm fiddling around with the ng2 library and noticed that the ChartOptions interface does not have all the properties as shown in the examples.  Perhaps those options are not implemented yet. I don't know yet.

Comment: This demo saved me!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had more or less the same issue. I figured out that in `chartjs-plugin-annotations`'s `index.d.tx` file there was a deprecated definition of **ChartOptions** interface, which collided against the one defined in `ng2-charts`.

So, in `~/project-folder/node_modules/@types/chartjs-plugin-annotation/index.d.ts`, change

```
// Extend the types from chart.js
declare module 'chart.js' {
  interface ChartOptions {
    // This is deprecated on master (not released yet)
    annotation?: ChartJsAnnotation.AnnotationConfig;
  }

  // This is the correct version on master (not released yet)
  // interface ChartPluginsOptions {
  //   annotation?: ChartJsAnnotation.AnnotationConfig;
  // }

  const Annotation: ChartJsAnnotation.AnnotationStatic;
}
```

to this

```
// Extend the types from chart.js
declare module 'chart.js' {
  // interface ChartOptions {
  //   // This is deprecated on master (not released yet)
  //   annotation?: ChartJsAnnotation.AnnotationConfig;
  // }

  // This is the correct version on master (not released yet)
  interface ChartPluginsOptions {
    annotation?: ChartJsAnnotation.AnnotationConfig;
  }

  const Annotation: ChartJsAnnotation.AnnotationStatic;
}
```

Doing so removed the compiler error for me.

Comment: Thank you! With your guidance I was finally able to find this issue, which has been fixed and merged a while ago, but for some reason there was no new release that includes this fix: https://github.com/chartjs/chartjs-plugin-annotation/issues/114